# C# Sending POST To PHP MYSQL but not recieving anything

Tags: c#, php, mysql

as I say in the tile ....... heres all my code 
MY PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php
    $DGURL = $_POST["url"];
    $DGUSER = $_POST["user"];
    $DGPASS = $_POST["pass"];
    function db_connect() {
        $hostname = '127.0.0.1';
        $db_user = 'root';
        $db_password = '';
        $db_name = 'hit';

        $conn = mysql_connect ($hostname, $db_user, $db_password) or 
            die (mysql_error()); 
        echo "Success.. Connected to MySQL...<br />"; 
        mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error()); 
        echo "Success.. Connected to Database...<br /> "; 

        return $conn;
    }

    $conn = db_connect();

    function insertData($DGURL, $DGUSER, $DGPASS) {
        $requete = "INSERT INTO data SET 
            Url='".$DGURL."', 
            Username='".$DGUSER."', 
            Password='".$DGPASS."'";
        mysql_query($requete) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    if(isset($_GET['DGURL']) && isset($_GET['DGUSER']) && isset($_GET['DGPASS'])) {
        insertData($_GET['DGURL'], $_GET['DGUSER'], $_GET['DGPASS']);
    }

?>
```

HERES MY C# CODE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        string URL = "http://localhost/test.php";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["url"] = "url";
        formData["user"] = "user";
        formData["user"] = "pass";

        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
        string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
        webClient.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Can some one please shed some light on this and help me fix and refin the script please help.
any help will be greatly usefull :)

Comment: Have you used something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to verify that the data is actually being sent correctly? And please please please resolve those [SQL Injection](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html) errors

Comment: Put echo `$var_dump($_POST)` after `<?php` in order to see more details of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Useful and simple sample [here](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/PHP/PostRequest_CSharp_php.html)

put this code inside the action of your form load, button click etc

```
     string URL = "http://www.softwareandfinance.com/PHP/portal_welcome.php";
     WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

     NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
     formData["username"] = "testuser";
     formData["password"] = "mypassword";

     byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
     string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
     Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
     webClient.Dispose();
```

Comment: username & password are POST parameters defined in php!